# Saves input in Single Line while using FileOutputStream

Tags: java, netbeans

While executing the code from **NetBeans**(IDE 8.0.2), the input has been saved as a single line even if I press enter to go to next line but the *uncanny* part is it works well if I execute the code using **Command Prompt**

```
class CreateFile{

public static void main(String... args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    //attach keyboard to DataInputStream
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);

    //attach file to FileOutputStream
    // using BufferedOutputStream and setting size (default 512)
    try (BufferedOutputStream bout = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("myFile.txt",true),1024)) {

        System.out.println("Enter text (@ at the end): ");
        char ch;
        //read character from DataInputStream into ch and the into FileOutputStream
        //repeat as long as the read character is not @
        while ((ch = (char) dis.read()) != '@') {
            bout.write(ch);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So Netbeans doesn't return the line terminator. So?

Comment: Yea I get it, but how do I fix this? I mean by assigning terminator by my own or by adding a terminator manually after successive input?

Comment: You can't fix Netbeans, and it doesn't matter in the slightest for your project. The end users aren't going to run your code via Netbeans. Just write it off as a development-environment anomaly.

Comment: Hey! 
can I do something to take the input into the next line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no overall solution to it. There can only be an IDE specific solution but you do not wan't to tie your implementation to the IDE.

The IDEs have there own handling for streams that are related to the console input and output. They may intercept them for their own purposes so the IDE (here NetBeans) may not populate the "line terminator" in the same way or even populate it at all like the windows or the linux command line will do it.

Comment: I see, 
how about manually inputting a terminator after 

` bout.wtite(ch); `

Comment: As I said: If the IDE does not populate the line terminator you do not know when to put a line terminator at all.